# Flutter - ThemeData use self-values

Tags: flutter

I want `titleTextStyle` value to be `headline2`

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline2: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The code in the example does not work so well.
What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
 appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "headLine",
          style:  Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5!,
         
        ),
      ),
```

or

````
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "headLine",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5!.fontSize,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Text(
        "headLine",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5!.fontSize,
        ),
      ),}

```
````

Comment: First of all thank you very much for the answer! I Know this way, this is the simple and clear way. But I want that by default every time I use `AppBar` it will use this `titleTextStyle` by default, without setting it every time. Do you know a way to do this? @Yeasin Sheikh

Comment: @Adi1231234 we took time answering your question - please follow up

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution you're looking for :

Create a function :  *(in an empty file)*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

PreferredSize? getAppBar(String appBarText, context) => PreferredSize(
    child: AppBar(
      title: Text(
        "$appBarText",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20), 
// or style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2, 
      ),
    ),
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0));
```

Then Pass it Around *anywhere* :

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: getAppBar("I'm an App Bar", context),
```

That's it!